# Working of Groovy grep and subscript

Tags: groovy

**SSCCE:**

```
def map = [
    1 : "One" ,
    2 : "Two" ,
    3 : "Three" ,
    4 : "Four" ,
    5 : "Five"
]

def list = [1,2,3,4,5]

// Using range in GREP
assert list.grep(0..2) == [1,2] // why not [1,2,3] ?? Why exclude index = 2 from the range ?
assert map.grep(0..2) == [] // why is this empty ??

// using subscript
assert list[0..2] == [1,2,3] // It  is [1,2,3]. As expected. Different from grep although same range
assert map[0..2] == null // huh ? No values ? Why is this not [] ?
```

My questions are in the SSCCE. What is it that I am missing ? What is wrong with my understanding ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `list.grep(0..2)` [finds all instances](http://mrhaki.blogspot.co.uk/2009/08/groovy-goodness-grep-method.html) in `list` which are in `[0, 1, 2]` hence `[1, 2]`
- The only way I can get `map.grep` to return anything is via `map.grep( LinkedHashMap.Entry )` or `map.grep( map.entrySet()[ 0..2 ] )`
- The `getAt` subscript operator on Lists works as you expect
- `0..2` is a valid key for a Map ie: `[ (0..2):'tim' ]`, so you cannot get a range of entries in this way